# Will camel respect bean method call annotated with @Transaction?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, apache-camel

I created a route with Apache camel, reading from a queue, do some processing and eventually store the processed items in the database. Here is the (slimmed down version) route:

```
fromF("activemq:queue:%s?username=%s&password=%s&transacted=true&transactionTimeout=5000", queueProperties
            .getStatusQueueName(), queueUsername, queuePassword)
            .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, StatusUpdate.class)
            .bean(shippingLabelPersister, "persist").id("status-update-persister")
        .routeId(ROUTE_ID);
```

The `shippingLabelPersister` persist method takes the message body and calls the shippingLabelService:

```
public void persist(@Body List<ShippingLabel> labels) {
  if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(labels)) {
    return;
  }

  List<ShippingLabel> savedLabels = shippingLabelService.saveAll(labels);

  for(ShippingLabel label : savedLabels) {
    logger.info("Updated shipment {} with status {} (timestamp: {})", label.getBarcode(), label.getStatus(), DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.format(label.getStatusChanged()));
  }
}
```

The `saveAll` method of the shippingLabel service has the @Transactional method.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<ShippingLabel> saveAll(List<ShippingLabel> labels) {
  if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(labels)) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

 return repository.saveAll(labels);
}
```

**I want to know if the persisting of the data will indeed be wrapped inside a transaction if it is called by the camel route?**

**Some background information**:
As you've seen I'm using beans for data persistence in this case. Rather than a camel component, for example the `camel-jpa-component`. The reason for this is that For now, regarding the scope and origin of the project, we want to reuse existing code as-is. We're creating microservices from a legacy monolithic application where we can't yet rewrite the whole route (yet), making full use of `the camel-jpa-component`. So I'm trying to see if my suggested solution is acceptable.

I'm also aware that camel provides a `transacted` method call from within the route, which uses springs transaction manager. However, I don't know if it would interfere with the call to the service which has the `@Transactional` annotation.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't? You can turn on debug logging for the Spring Transaction to see if it does :-) No just joking. Sure it works. Camel uses Spring

Comment: In the annotated `@Transactional` method you can log the output of `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()`, if it is true then you are covered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider creating test case for this:
let the labels list contain last ShippingLabel that is incorrect for the database (too long or something), assert that none of ShippingLabel is inserted,
refactor saveAll() to call nonTransactionalSaveAll(), which should save all but the incorrect ShippingLabel.